# Bootstrap 3 responsive nav bar not reacting

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have some drop down items that are rather long and they are wrapping down to the next level otherwise overflowing. I am not very familiar with @media but when I go down to mobile it shows the drop down collapse nav vs. the tablet or smaller laptop it does not act responsively. Is there something I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

`http://blog.sobecreative.com/clients/test/index2.html`

Comment: I'm seeing this in the error Console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://blog.sobecreative.com/clients/test/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: @SeanFujiwara good catch uploaded.

Comment: You could do everything on that page with about 15 lines of CSS, so I would suggest you learn CSS and skip bootstrap. You are going to run into problems every step of the way.

Comment: I am using bootstrap mostly for responsiveness. I am just wondering why in ~1024 width why the media query is not firing...

Comment: Try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nav-bar

Answer (score 0):

You must have the 'jquery.js' called before the 'bootstrap.min.js' in your html code. Else tapping on menu button in mobile view doesn't work.